# Dynamic update of QTextBrowser in a Qdialog from a file(that gets updated by another job)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextbrowser

I have a log file that gets updated while the job is running. I want the text content displayed in the text browser, and that should be updated dynamically.

**.h file**

```
public:

    void fillloginfo();

    void initializeQTimer();

    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

    void fillLogInfoChronically(const QString& logFilePath);

private:

    QTimer* m_Timer;

    QString m_logFilePath;

    std::ifstream m_logFileStream;

public slots:

    void fillLogInfoChronicallySlot();
```

**.cpp file**

```
void logdialog::initializeQTimer(){

    m_Timer = NULL;

    //create the timer object
    m_Timer = new QTimer(this);

    QObject::connect(m_Timer,SIGNAL(timeout()), this,SLOT(fillLogInfoChronicallySlot()));

 }

void logdialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    m_Timer->stop();

    if ( m_logFileStream.is_open()){
         m_logFileStream.close();
    }
}



void logdialog::fillLogInfoChronically(const QString &logFilePath)
{
    uilog->textBrowser->clear();

    m_LastLinePos = 0;

    m_logFilePath = logFilePath;

    std::string m_logFilePathStr= m_logFilePath.toStdString();
    m_logFileStream.open(m_logFilePathStr.c_str());

    if (m_logFileStream.is_open()){

        fillloginfo();

        m_Timer->start(1000);
    }
}

void logdialog::fillloginfo()
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(m_logFileStream,line)){
        uilog->textBrowser->append(QString::fromStdString(line));
    }  
}

void logdialog::fillLogInfoChronicallySlot()
{
    fillloginfo();
}
```

So, I am able to read the file only on the first call, rest of the calls to get an update from the file are not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How often is the log written to ?

Comment: I don't have a control over the log generated. I launch a job from my tool, and that updates the log file.

Comment: Then, are you sure the log is updated ? Because `getline` is blocking and you could wait indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, I am sure log is getting updated, the block of the code I have written in the first iter is reading the file, but in the consecutive calls by the signal slot mechanism is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `std::ios::clear()` in the input stream after the initial reading. When you read the whole file, it sets the `failbit` in the stream and refuses to continue reading, even though the file has changed in the meantime.

In your case you must do before reading again:

```
void logdialog::fillloginfo()
{
    std::string line;
    m_logFileStream.clear();
    while (getline(m_logFileStream,line)){
        uilog->textBrowser->append(QString::fromStdString(line));
    }
}
```

The complete code is in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46068390)